# How to accept image as user input by clicking on Tkinter button in Python?

Tags: python, image, image-processing, tkinter, file-upload

I am writing a program on image processing that needs to get an image as user input after clicking on a Tkinter button.

Here's my code:

```
root = tk.Tk()
#root.withdraw()
def file():
    file = askopenfile(mode ='r', filetypes =[('JPG File', '*.jpg'),('PNG File','*.png')], encoding="utf8")
    if file is not None:
        content = file.read()
        print(content)


open = tk.Button(root, text ="Open Image",command= lambda : file())
open.pack()
root.mainloop()
```

Error:

```
Exception in Tkinter callback
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:\Users\Admin\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python37\lib\tkinter\__init__.py", line 1705, in __call__
    return self.func(*args)
  File "C:/Users/Admin/.PyCharmCE2019.1/config/scratches/scratch_3.py", line 18, in <lambda>
    open = tk.Button(root, text ="Open Image",command= lambda : file())
  File "C:/Users/Admin/.PyCharmCE2019.1/config/scratches/scratch_3.py", line 12, in file
    file = askopenfile(mode ='r', filetypes =[('JPG File', '*.jpg'),('PNG File','*.png')], encoding="utf8")
  File "C:\Users\Admin\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python37\lib\tkinter\filedialog.py", line 396, in askopenfile
    filename = Open(**options).show()
  File "C:\Users\Admin\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python37\lib\tkinter\commondialog.py", line 43, in show
    s = w.tk.call(self.command, *w._options(self.options))
_tkinter.TclError: bad option "-encoding": must be -defaultextension, -filetypes, -initialdir, -initialfile, -multiple, -parent, -title, or -typevariable
```

Comment: As the error said, `encoding` is not a valid option of `askopenfile()`.  Also you need to use binary mode "rb" to open image file.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is because you are passing the wrong mode to `askopenfile`. You are passing  `mode='r'` but it should be `mode='rb'` since pictures are bytes also you need to remove the `encoding` argument.

Comment: The error of the question is not on the file open mode.

Comment: No it is `_tkinter.TclError: bad option "-encoding": must be -defaultextension, -filetypes, -initialdir, -initialfile, -multiple, -parent, -title, or -typevariable` which means `askopenfile()` does not support `encoding` option.

Comment: After changing `mode='r'` to `mode='rb'` and run the code, it stills get the error.

Comment: If you did not remove the option `encoding` from `askopenfile(...)`, you should get the same error when the button is clicked.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/223667/discussion-between-abhigyan-jaiswal-and-acw1668).